# Docker compose can't open python file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I runned docker compose file using the `docker-compose up` command that supposed to run some python script, but I got an error that says that he cannot open the python sciprt I gave him, this is the error:

> python3: can't open file '//relay.py': [Errno 2] No such file or director

this is the full error when running the command:
[image from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjbtX.png)

**Can someone help me fix this error?**
this is my files directory:

```
/dockers/docker-compose.yml
/dockers/relay-codes/relay.py
/dockers/relay-codes/Dockerfile
```

**Docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  relays:
    build: ./relay-codes
    volumes:
      - ./relay-codes:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 5001:9898
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:latest

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "python3", "./relay.py" ]
```

Comment: Its probably cause  that file is not present hence its not able to execute the command. Either u can create that file in your repo or else you must have forgot to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY relay.py /usr/src/app/
CMD ["python3", "relay.py"]
```

Answer (score -2):

The exception is providing you all the clue that you need. There's no file at that location.

Comment: I tried this and got this error:

"python3: can't open file '//./relay-codes/relay.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: for some reason its adding // before the command